# SubString StringBuilder c#

Tags: c#, exception, stringbuilder

I'm trying :

```
1  string pal = "Juan     1David     1Correa";
2  StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(pal);
3  Console.writeline( sb.ToString(0,9) );
4  Console.writeline( sb.ToString(10,14) );
5  Console.writeline( sb.ToString(15,26) );
```

But in the 4 line It throws an exception.

Why?

Comment: What is the exception thrown? This also strikes me as an odd use of `StringBuilder`, what are you trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The second argument to [**`StringBuilder.ToString(int, int)`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fyx7s61s.aspx) represents the *length* of the desired sub-string, not its end-index.

> Retrieves a substring from this
>   instance. The substring starts at a
>   specified character position and **has a
>   specified length.**

For example, the last statement should probably be:

```
Console.WriteLine(sb.ToString(15, 12));
```

On another note, If all you want is to get sub-strings from the original string, you could just use the [**`String.Substring(int, int)`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aka44szs.aspx) method.

Comment: @Daniel G. R.: To correct your last statement, if you are using `Substring`, you could try `Console.WriteLine( sb.ToString().Substring(15) );`

Answer (score 3):

Second parameter is length, so it should be

```
Console.writeline( sb.ToString(10,5) );
```

Comment: Actually that should be 5 to get the chars at index 10, 11, 12, 13, and 14.

Answer (score 2):

[The docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fyx7s61s.aspx) clearly state that `ArgumentOutOfRangeException` will be thrown when "The sum of startIndex and length is greater than the length of the current instance."

Answer (score 1):

Second parameter is length but not a last index. So in your case 15+26 = 41 which is out of the bounds.

Answer (score 1):

The second argument is length, not "end character". It cannot find 14 characters starting from 10th - hence the error.

Answer (score 1):

When I run this, the exception is thrown on line 5, which makes perfect sense, as there are not enough characters in your input string to generate 26 characters starting at 15.

Answer (score 0):

first of all you should document us which exception you get instead of leaving us in the dark to try to figure it out ourselves, then as a guess, I would say that your string does not contain more than 24 chars...

Answer (score 0):

The `StringBuilder.ToString` method does not work as you expect.  The parameters are:

1. **startIndex**: The starting position of the substring in this instance.
2. **length**: The length of the substring.

So you are starting at index 15 and trying to get the next 26 characters, which goes beyond the length of the string.

The documentation can be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fyx7s61s.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Please double-check that your string contains space characters within it and not **tab** characters. This is the only reason you can have an exception on line **4**. But even if your string contains spaces you *will* have an exception on line **5** because 26 is the lenght of the substring, not the index of the last character.